# Lifnei iver and converts

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, machlokes, lifnei-iver, leniencies

[Is it lifnei iver if you enable someone to violate a strict interpretation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77743/33665) this question asks a related question about Lifnei iver about machlokets. The answer seems to be you can’t have someone violate the instructions of their rabbinic authority. My question is, what about having a convert (ger tzedek), do something which there is a Halacha machloket. For example non-Glatt kosher meat. Would giving a lenient opinion be considered Lifnei iver, if so are there exceptions, and if yes are there exceptions?

Comment: What difference does it make if they're a convert? Just generally, someone who's not as knowledgeable and trusts you on halacha, right?

Comment: A convert does adopt a tradition when converting, typically the one of his newly adopted community, or the Rav he learned with.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between people born as Jews or people who converted as Jews. Both have a set of traditions/minhagim/chumrot they follow and you can't push them to transgress those